# How to make custom search & filter page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make custom search page where I can filter results as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Currently my problem is that all the items of the list are coming in a single category while I want a grouped view according to different categories e.g. "Device Features", "Mobile Phone Operating System", etc. So far I've written below piece of PHP code:

```
<?php 
                        $listCategories = get_categories();
                        if(isset($listCategories) && !empty($listCategories)){


                    ?>
                        <div class="list-section">
                            <h3 class="list-heading">Topics</h3>
                            <ul id="post-grid">
                                <?php 
                                    foreach($listCategories as $categories){
                                            $total_post = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'post', 'category'=>$categories->term_id, 'posts_per_page'=>'-1'));
                                            $total_post = count($total_post);
                                ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="cat<?php echo $categories->term_id; ?>" data-tax="category" data-name="<?php echo $categories->name; ?>" class="category_check" value="<?php echo $categories->term_id; ?>">
                                        <label class="css-label" for="cat<?php echo $categories->term_id; ?>">
                                            <span class="filter-name"><?php echo $categories->name; ?></span>
                                            <span class="filter-count"><?php echo $total_post; ?></span>
                                            <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are these Categories that is being displayed? There are lots of plugins that give this feature. If you want your own logic, You can create custom page and filter it wirh jQuery and AJAX

Comment: @SudharshanNair there are post_types & taxonomy on left side, also how to post the checkbox value and create a wp_query.

Comment: You have to customise to create this type. From WP_Query you can get desired results with post type and then you can display it.

Comment: As you've obviously put some work into solving your problem, you may want to edit the original question so that it doesn't keep getting down votes.

Comment: @JustinR. Thanks for suggestion I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created my own custom plugin for searching and filtering the search result.

**1. Plugin file (index.php)**

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Search and Filter
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org
Description: Search and Filter
Author: Naveen
Version: 1.0
*/

class SearchAndFilter{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'AddScript'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_affordance_search_data' , array($this, 'AffordanceSearchData'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_noprev_affordance_search_data' , array($this, 'AffordanceSearchData'));

        add_action('wp_ajax_affordance_search_page_data' , array($this, 'AffordanceSearchPageData'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_noprev_affordance_search_page_data' , array($this, 'AffordanceSearchPageData'));
        add_shortcode('Search', array($this, 'CreateShortcode'));
    }

    public function AddScript()
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('saf-app', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/app.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_localize_script('saf-app', 'my_ajax_object', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    }   

    function CreateShortcode($atts)
    {
        ob_start();
        $keyword = $_REQUEST['s'];
    ?>
        <form action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="s" id="search_keyword" value="<?php echo $keyword; ?>" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search..." />
        </form>
        <div class="search-suggestion"></div>
    <?php 
        $output = ob_get_clean();
        return $output;
    }

    // search autocomplete
    function AffordanceSearchData()
    {
        $args = array('post_type'=>array('post'),'status'=>'publish');
        $output = '';
        $output = '<ul class="grid effect-3" id="grid">';

        if(isset($_POST['keyword']) && !empty($_POST['keyword']))
        {
            $args['s'] =  $_POST['keyword'];
        }

        $wpPosts = new WP_Query($args);

        if($wpPosts->have_posts()) : 
        while($wpPosts->have_posts()) :
        $wpPosts->the_post();
        $output .= '<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        endwhile;
        endif;
        $output .= '<li><a href="'.home_url().'?s='.$_POST['keyword'].'">See All Result of '.$_POST['keyword'].' </a></li>';
        $output .= '</ul>';
        wp_reset_query();
        echo $output; die;
    }

    // filters search data
    function AffordanceSearchPageData()
    {
        $args = array('post_type'=>'post','status'=>'publish');
        $output = '';
        $output .= '<ul class="grid effect-3" id="grid">';
        if(isset($_POST['keyword']) && !empty($_POST['keyword']))
        {
            $args['s'] =  $_POST['keyword'];
        }

        if(isset($_POST['page_number']) && !empty($_POST['page_number']) && $_POST['page_number'] != 1){
            $args['paged'] =  $_POST['page_number'];
        }

        if(isset($_POST['categories']) && !empty($_POST['categories'])){
            $args['cat'] =  $_POST['categories'];
        }

        $wpPosts = new WP_Query($args);

        if($wpPosts->have_posts()) : 
        while($wpPosts->have_posts()) :
        $wpPosts->the_post();

        $output .= '<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <h3 class="resources-content-heading"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>
                        <p class="resources-content-description">'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>
                        <div class="resources-action-area">
                            <a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="more-link">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>';
        endwhile;
        else :
            $output .= "No records";
        endif;
        wp_reset_query();
        $output .= the_posts_pagination();
        $output .= '</main>';
        echo $output; die;
    }
}

new SearchAndFilter();
```

**2. Js File (app.js)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // on searching keyword
    $('#search_keyword').keyup(function () {
        var inputvalue = $(this).val();

        if (inputvalue != '') {
            GetSuggestion(inputvalue);
        }
    });

    // on pagination click
    $('.ajaxclick').on('click', "a", function () {
        var page_number = $(this).attr('data-page-num');
        //console.log(page_number);
        var current_page = $('.ajaxclick .current').attr('data-page-num');
        var keyword = $('#search_keyword').val();
        GetSearchData(keyword, page_number);
    });

    // on category select
    $('.category_check').on('click', function () {
        var page_number = 1;
        var keyword = $('#search_keyword').val();
        var blogWrapper = $('.blogWrapper');
        var catTagHTML = '<ul>';
        blogWrapper.find('input.category_check:checked').each(function () {
            catTagHTML += '<li><a class="exclude_cat" href="javascript:void(0)" data-cat-id="' + $(this).attr('value') + '">' + $(this).attr('data-name') + '</a></li>';
        });
        $('#selected-category-tags').html(catTagHTML);
        GetSearchData(keyword, page_number);
    });

    // on tag click
    $('#selected-category-tags').on('click', "a.exclude_cat", function () {
        var page_number = 1;
        var keyword = $('#search_keyword').val();
        var catID = $(this).attr('data-cat-id');
        $('#cat' + catID).attr('checked', false);
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
        GetSearchData(keyword, page_number);
    });

    function GetSuggestion(keyword) {
        var formData = {
            'action': 'affordance_search_data',
            'keyword': keyword
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.search-suggestion').html(data);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    function GetSearchData(keyword, page_number) {
        if (page_number == '') {
            page_number = 1;
        }

        var blogWrapper = $('.blogWrapper');
        var categories = [];

        blogWrapper.find('input.category_check:checked').each(function () {
            categories.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });

        var formData = {
            'action': 'affordance_search_page_data',
            'page_number': page_number,
            'keyword': keyword,
            'categories': categories,
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.site-main').html(data);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here I'm using ajax to achieve this functionality.